# How to schedule task twice a month

Tags: laravel-5

```
$schedule->command('sitemap:sitemap_xml_generate')->monthly();
```

In the above command we can scedule once a month, if i want to schedule **twice a month or 15 day once**, how can I write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This works fine. I am running the cron job on 3 and 18 of the month.

```
$schedule->command('sitemap:sitemap_xml_generate')->cron('0 0 3,18 * *');
```

cron('0 0 3,18 * *') -> Argument are 'minute hour day(we can specify multiple date seperated by comma) month year'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `daily()` together with `when()` method and inside `when` add suitable constrain for your task. For example, run task every month for 1,7,20 days:

```
$schedule->command('sitemap:sitemap_xml_generate')->daily()->when(function () 
{
    $days = [1,7,20];
    $today = Carbon::today();

    return in_array($today->day, $days);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this if you dont have specific day as a constrain is to use Scheduler's method `twiceMonthly`.

Eg:

```
 $schedule->command('sitemap:sitemap_xml_generate')
        ->twiceMonthly();
```

Defination for the method looks something like

```
twiceMonthly($first = 1, $second = 16, $time = '0:0') //should be able to override.
```

Hope this helps